# When is Midrash also History?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I think the [midrash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/midrash) and [history](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tags need to be a bit better defined.

When does a question count as Midrash and when does it count as History?

Is a question about where the Jews in the desert got all their animals for the daily sacrifice from, a question of Midrash or History?

I think proposed, lengthier descriptions of the tags might be helpful.

Comment: Also how does [tag:parshanut-torah-comment] fit in?

Answer (score 1):

For me:

`History` is something which any reasonable person can agree happened. The events themselves are also spoken about or recorded outside of Jewish Religious texts.

`Midrash`, is an interpretation based on the *Tanach*, which is not directly stated within the text itself.

`Parshanut-torah-comment` is a discussion of the *Torah* as it is written about either in the Tanach or Talmud.